# Basic selector issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a hidden div on the click of a link (and hide a bundle of others). This is the code for the simplest example, one link, one div.
For some reason, it's not working. If I select the div by class, fine, shows, if I select it by ID it doesn't. The addClass('active') on the activating link works so I know my programme flow and selection of the link is correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>  
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {

    $( "#deal-147" ).click( function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('active') ){ // if we clicked on this just hide it and remove class active

            $( this ).removeClass('active');
            $( ".deal-summary" ).hide();    

        } else {


            $( ".deal-link" ).removeClass('active'); //remove class from all
            $( "#deal-summary-147" ).show(); //doesn't work
            $( "#deal-summary-147" ).addClass('reveal'); //doesn't work
            //$( ".deal-summary" ).show(); //does work
            $( "#deal-147" ).addClass('active');//does work

        }
    } );
});
</script>

<a id="deal-147" class="deal-link" href="#">Deal summary</a>
<div id="#deal-summary-147" class="deal-summary">
 <p>some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Include your html coding in your question

Comment: don't put a `#` in the div id in your HTML - just use `<div id="deal-summary-147" class="deal-summary">`

Comment: Simple as that! "there's none so blind" - shame you can't delete numpty questions, thanks dude.

Comment: Instead of `jQuery("document")` use `jQuery(document)`